# unique_ptr < 0 OR what does less than operator do?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unique-ptr

I am dealing with code that has been written not by me. I have this statement:

```cpp
// p is type of std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>
if (p < 0) { /* throw an exception */ }
```

So what does `p < 0` mean in this context?
On [the documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp), I believe my case is `16) y < nullptr`,
where `0` is `nullptr`.

But what does it do?

Comment: Based on the fact that, in x64, canonical pointers in kernel range have the upper bit set, it could be a (stupid hardcoded) way to check if a pointer belongs to the kernel space - if the answer below is correct though, then no.

Comment: In WINAPI `p==-1` is an invalid handle. Since `2^64` is a ridicolously huge number any sensible `p` is always positive. So `p<0` checks for invalid handle of WINAPI. This isn''t a good code.

Comment: @OP: Could you clarify a bit in which context this code is used? Is it used on Linux or Windows? Is the value of the pointer related to some WINAPI code? I think if you clarified that, the comments above may be good answers.

Comment: @ALX23z But should a WINAPI handle be of type `uint8_t*` (or even array of `uint8_t`)? I think they are `void*`, aren't they?

Comment: @walnut they aren't `void*` they have macro HANDLE_PTR or something which is basically `long*` iirc.

Answer (score 2):

> unique_ptr < 0 OR what does less than operator do?

It matches the overload (11) on cppreference `operator<(const unique_ptr&, nullptr_t);`. 0 implicitly converts to `std::nullptr_t`. As per the documentation, the result is `std::less<unique_ptr<T,D>::pointer>()(x.get(), nullptr)`.

The result is implementation defined, but unconditionally false on probably most systems. Presumably on an exotic system where null doesn't have the binary representation of 0, the result might be true.

> I believe my case is 16)

(16) is the same other way around: `0 > unique_ptr`. The result is same.

Comment: But is `0` considered `nullptr` by the compiler? I think that's what he's wondering. Doesn't make sense to me either, at least.

Comment: @alteredinstance 0 is not "considered" `nullptr` (or depends on what you mean by consideration). 0 implicitly converts to `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: That's what I assumed. I'm wondering if there is any documentation on the implicit conversion of `0` to `nullptr`, since I've only seen the two compatible with boolean comparisons. They're comparable, but I was under the impression that they are not convertible.

Comment: @alteredinstance The conversion doesn't happen the other way around. `int x = nullptr` is ill-formed.

Comment: Sorry, I reworded my question to omit the "other way around" part. Wasn't quite what I meant to say.

Comment: @alteredinstance `std::nullptr_t` was designed to be usable with any null pointer constant; not just `nullptr`. 0 (as well as 0L for example) are null pointer constants, so it is intention that they can be used to create a `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks!

Comment: more precisely, we have `auto p = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(pos_number);` then we change data `p.get()`; so now it completely does not make any sense, does it to you?

Comment: @Sagid No, it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Check that `operator <` is not overloaded somewhere in your code base. That seems to be the only way how `(p < 0)` could be `true`.

Example:

```
bool operator< (const std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>&, int) { return true; }

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> p;
    std::cout << (p < 0) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
1
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6eea6dfb21f4a105)

Otherwise as others have said, `0` implicitly converts to `std::nullptr_t`, which would select the `bool operator<(const unique_ptr<T, D>& x, nullptr_t)` overload which would call `std::less(p, 0)` which would return `false` (even on Windows with a `-1` pointer value).

Comment: It does not *necessarily* return `false`. It is either implementation-defined or unspecified (I am not sure.) But I agree that it probably will return `false` on most (all?) implementations. See also answer by @eerorika

Answer (score 0):

This expression matches with [this template operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp) (0 being converted to `nullptr`):

```
template <class T, class D>
bool operator<(const unique_ptr<T, D>& x, nullptr_t);
```

This returns `std::less<unique_ptr<T,D>::pointer>()(p.get(), nullptr)` which is always false (as [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) is a strict order functor) ([demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84055d4790a9df5a)).

Comment: It does not *always* return `false`. Whether it does is either implementation-defined or unspecified. It probably does always return `false` though on most (all?) current implementations.

Comment: @walnut Unless a question explicitly asks about what the Standard says (through the [tag:language-lawyer] tag for instance), I try to answer from a practical point of view. All practical implementation of `std::less` return `false`.

Comment: That is fine, I just didn't find your reasoning ("*as std::less is a strict order functor*") convincing. It can be a strict order without returning `false`. The practical reason would be that the zero pointer value is represented by the lowest possible address or something along those lines.